# jquery chosen dropdown does not get updated for style change hide/show

Tags: jquery, css, select

I have a dropdown implemented through the chosen plugin,if i had to hide the dropdown on certain event, how will i do it.

```
    $("#sel_searchStatus_chosen").css("display", "none");
        $("#sel_searchStatus").val("");
```

I want to hide the dropdown with id sel_searchStatus.

Is the above code correct or does it have any custom functions like the trigger update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont set the id to choosen directly. The plugin automatically hide your select box and display the choosen.

```
$("#sel_searchStatus + div.chosen-container").css("display", "none");
```

here **+** indicates the next sibling of selected element

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple.

```
$("#sel_searchStatus_chosen").on('event', function() {
  this.hide();
});
```

'event' depending on the event you want to use f.e. click, and use .show() on the event that you want it to show up again.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use following code , as chosen plugin appends _chzn after select box id

```
$('#sel_searchStatus_chzn').hide()
```

Comment: thanks, but this is what i dont want exactly, i dont want to use the id generated by chosen plugin.